# Branch prediction exercise

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture

Assume a machine with a 7-stage pipeline. Assume that branches are resolved in the sixth stage. Assume that 30% of instructions are branches.

3.1 How many instructions of wasted work are there per branch mis-prediction on this machine?

3.2 Assume 1000 instructions are on the correct path of a program and assume a branch predictor accuracy of 10%. How many instructions are fetched on this machine?

3.3  Let’s say we modified the machine so that it used dual path execution (where an equal number of instructions are fetched from each of the two branch paths). Assume branches are resolved before new branches are fetched. Write how many instructions would be fetched in this case, as a function of N. (Please show your work for full credit.)

Attempt at a solution

3.1) 4 assuming bypassing at s6

3.2) 30% brancches, predictor accuracy: 10%, 1000 Ins, so there are 300 branches and 700 normal instructions. Let x be total number of instructions fetched, so

$$0.1x=700$$
$$x=7000$$

Therefore, 7000 ins were fetched

3.3) I am not sure about this one. It confuses me in the following way, how do we execute instructions on different path without considering dependences?. What is a dual path in this case?. Can u explain in more detail what this questio is asking?.

Comment: @Joe C slow down my friend. I don't expect you to do my homework. I expect instead orientation, advice, help. Can u provide that?. Did u see I put an attempt at a solution?.

Answer (score 0):

3.1   5 instructions, no bypassing

3.2   Assume base CPI = 1
CPI = 1 + 30% * 90% * 5 = 2.35
Branches causes 135% slow down.
2350 instructions are fetched on this machine.